# Thesis SPSS Regression help

Tags: regression, spss, interaction, econometrics, linear

I'm currently working on my thesis and would like some advice for the statistical analysis section.

My hypotheses are:

*H1: Firms that belong to a product industry are more likely to establish a wholly owned subsidiary when investing abroad than firms that belong to a service industry.*

*H2: Firms that belong to a primary industry are more likely to establish a wholly owned subsidiary when investing abroad than firms that belong to a secondary industry.*

*H3: A firm's degree of internationalisation positively moderates the relationship hypothesized in H1.*

*H4: A firm’s degree of internationalisation positively moderates the relationship hypothesized in H2.*

Thus: the dependent variable is "total stake in foreign affiliates" (dichotomous: 1=100% stake; 0= <100%) The independent variable is industry class (dichotomous as well: primary=1; secondary=0 for H2 for example). The moderator variable in H3 and H4 is measured through a sales ratio. Control variables include firm size,age and performance.

From my supervisor I know I'll have to apply a hierarchical regression model (First regress independent var*control variables, then also include the dependent variables, then also include the moderator variable etc.)
Now, I'm kind of in doubt about which type of SPSS regression to use.
I was thinking about binary logistic regression as the IV is of dichotomous nature, but would this also work with both IV and DV being dichotomous? I'm also not sure how to incorporate an interaction term.

This is all pretty new to me,so would love to hear your opinion and suggestions!